# Why "Vue is not defined" when using Vue 3 + Vuex 4?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, stackblitz

I'm trying to migrate form props to Vuex 4. But when I import Vuex I get Vue is not defined.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-t8q9t9

[image]

Comment: Did you install vuejs? and added? import Vue from 'vue'

Comment: @gguney const { createApp } = require('vue');
import App from './App.vue';
import BootstrapVue3 from 'bootstrap-vue-3';
import { store } from './store.js';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css';

createApp({App}).use(BootstrapVue3).use(store).mount('#app');

Answer (score -2):

In your entry point, that you import Vuex. Add this:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuex from "vuex"
Vue.use(Vuex)
```

Remember install dependences